# Referencing a common instance from a DI constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Using Ninject DI, I have implemented two interfaces that I instantiate from my MVC controllers.  For example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;
   private readonly IAssetService _AssetService;

   public MyController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IAssetService assetService)
   {
      this._UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
      this._AssetService = assetService;
   }

   // Controller actions etc. 
}
```

In my Ninject module I have created the following bindings:

```
public class DomainModule : NinjectModule
{
   public override void Load()
   {
      Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
         .To<SqlUnitOfWork>()
         .InRequestScope()
         .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "MyDb.Database");

      Bind<IAssetService>()
         .To<FileSystemAssetService>()
         .WithConstructorArgument("rootPath", "C:\\DataStore");
   }
}
```

I now want to inject the `IUnitOfWork` instance into my `IAssetService`  so I have considered making this a property of `IAssetService` and modifying my controllers as follows:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;
   private readonly IAssetService _AssetService;

   public MyController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IAssetService assetService)
   {
      this._UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
      this._AssetService = assetService;

      this._AssetService.UnitOfWork = this._UnitOfWork;
   }

   // Controller actions etc. 
}
```

but I wondered if there was a better/cleaner way of doing this using a different DI technique - ideally I would like to add the `IUnitOfWork` to the `AssetService` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then why not simply inject the `IUnitOfWork` into the `AssetService`?

```
public class FileSystemAssetService : IAssetService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly string rootPath;

    public FileSystemAssetService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, string rootPath)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.rootPath = rootPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly, I had not realised that the .InRequestScope() effectively creates a single object that is referenced by all the constructors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No probs. Glad I could help :)